# How to do validation for <q-select> using vee-validate?

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework, vee-validate

Below is the example on which I want to check the validation(select at least one of the option).

```
<q-select
      multiple
      inverted
      color="dark"
      stack-label="Roles"
      separator
      v-model="multipleSelect"
      :options="options1"
      v-validate="'required|in:x-builder,rt-builder,commune,matrix,blade-runner,optocoupler,admin'"
      />
<div class="containerError">   <i v-show="errors.has('role')" class="fa fa-warning"></i>
      <span v-show="errors.has('role')" class="text-negative text-right">{{ errors.first('role') }}</span>
</div>
```